# trying to get a table to look right

Tags: tables

Would anyone be able to tell me, for the following code, how I get vertical lines at the left and right of the second table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs,ulem,tikz, caption}


\begin{document}

\def \Alt{\mathrm{Alt}}
\section{Alternating products of Poincar\'{e} series}
\subsection{Tabulation of the main results}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||c c||} 
 \hline
Weyl group & $\prod_{I\subseteq S} W_{I}(u)^{(-1)^{|I|+n}}$ \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 $A_{n}$ & $\frac{1-u^{n+1}}{1-u^{n}}$ \\ \hline
 $B_{n}$ & $\frac{1-u^{2n}}{1-u^{n}}$ \\ \hline
 $D_{n}$ & $\frac{1-u^{2n-2}}{1-u^{n}}$ \\ \hline
 $E_{6}$ & $\frac{(1-u^{12})(1-u^{9})}{(1-u^{8})(1-u^{6})}$ \\ \hline
 $E_{7}$ & $\frac{(1-u^{18})(1-u^{14})}{(1-u^{9})(1-u^{7})}$ \\ \hline
 $E_{8}$ & $\frac{(1-u^{30})(1-u^{24})(1-u^{20})}{(1-u^{12})(1-u^{10})(1-u^{8})}$ \\ \hline
 $F_{4}$ & $\frac{(1-u^{12})(1-u^{8})}{(1-u^{6})(1-u^{4})}$ \\ \hline
 $G_{2}$ & $\frac{1-u^{5}}{1-u^{2}}$ \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

 \bigskip

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{llc cll}
 \hline
 Affine Weyl group & $\prod_{I\subseteq S} W_{I}(u)^{(-1)^{|I|+n}}$ \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline \hline
 $\tilde{A_{n}}$ & $n+1, n+1, n+1, \ldots n+1$ ($n$ times) \\ \hline
 $\tilde{B_{n}}$ & $n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n$ \\ \hline
 $\tilde{C_{n}}$ & $n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n$ \\ \hline
 $\tilde{D_{n}}$ & $n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n-4, 2n-3, 2n-2, 2n-2, 2n-2$ \\ \hline
 $\tilde{E_{6}}$ & $7, 9, 9, 11, 12, 12$ \\ \hline
 $\tilde{E_{7}}$ & $8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18$ \\ \hline
 $\tilde{E_{8}}$ & $9, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 23, 29$ \\ \hline
 $\tilde{F_{4}}$ & $5, 7, 8, 11$ \\ \hline
 $\tilde{G_{2}}$ & $3, 5$ \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `|ll|`. You are declaring 6 columns but using only 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written `l`s instead of `|`s. The letter "l" and not the vertical bar.

You want to have `\begin{tabular}{||c c||}` like in your first table. Right now, you have defined 6 columns (two left-aligned, two centre-aligned, and two left-aligned) but you have only two columns in use.

However, your tables are quite hard to read. That many lines and colliding characters. I would like to recommend you to use `booktabs`

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
%\usepackage{caption} % if you want to use floats
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \section{Alternating products of Poincar\'{e} series}
    \subsection{Tabulation of the main results} 
    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
        \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}c<{$}} 
            \toprule
            \text{Weyl group} & \prod_{I\subseteq S} W_{I}(u)^{(-1)^{|I|+n}} \\
            \midrule
            A_{n} & \frac{1-u^{n+1}}{1-u^{n}} \\ 
            B_{n} & \frac{1-u^{2n}}{1-u^{n}} \\ 
            D_{n} & \frac{1-u^{2n-2}}{1-u^{n}} \\ 
            E_{6} & \frac{(1-u^{12})(1-u^{9})}{(1-u^{8})(1-u^{6})} \\ 
            E_{7} & \frac{(1-u^{18})(1-u^{14})}{(1-u^{9})(1-u^{7})} \\ 
            E_{8} & \frac{(1-u^{30})(1-u^{24})(1-u^{20})}{(1-u^{12})(1-u^{10})(1-u^{8})} \\ 
            F_{4} & \frac{(1-u^{12})(1-u^{8})}{(1-u^{6})(1-u^{4})} \\ 
            G_{2} & \frac{1-u^{5}}{1-u^{2}} \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}} 
            \toprule
            \text{Affine Weyl group} & \prod_{I\subseteq S} W_{I}(u)^{(-1)^{|I|+n}} \\
            \midrule
            \tilde{A_{n}} & n+1, n+1, n+1, \ldots n+1 \quad (n~\text{times}) \\ 
            \tilde{B_{n}} & n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n \\ 
            \tilde{C_{n}} & n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n \\ 
            \tilde{D_{n}} & n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n-4, 2n-3, 2n-2, 2n-2, 2n-2 \\ % this line is too long for your document. You have to split or rephrase.
            \tilde{E_{6}} & 7, 9, 9, 11, 12, 12 \\ 
            \tilde{E_{7}} & 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18 \\ 
            \tilde{E_{8}} & 9, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 23, 29 \\ 
            \tilde{F_{4}} & 5, 7, 8, 11 \\ 
            \tilde{G_{2}} & 3, 5 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}    
%\begin{table
%   \centering
%   \caption{some caption}\label{tab:someLabel}
%   \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}l<{$}} 
%       \toprule
%       \text{Affine Weyl group} & \prod_{I\subseteq S} W_{I}(u)^{(-1)^{|I|+n}} \\
%       \midrule
%       \tilde{A_{n}} & n+1, n+1, n+1, \ldots n+1 \quad (n~\text{times}) \\ 
%       \tilde{B_{n}} & n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n \\ 
%       \tilde{C_{n}} & n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n \\ 
%       \tilde{D_{n}} & n+1, n+2, \ldots 2n-4, 2n-3, 2n-2, 2n-2, 2n-2 \\ 
%       \tilde{E_{6}} & 7, 9, 9, 11, 12, 12 \\ 
%       \tilde{E_{7}} & 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18 \\ 
%       \tilde{E_{8}} & 9, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 23, 29 \\ 
%       \tilde{F_{4}} & 5, 7, 8, 11 \\ 
%       \tilde{G_{2}} & 3, 5 \\ \bottomrule
%   \end{tabular}
%\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The last examples (commented out) shows how to use such a table in a float. Much nicer speaking of typographical issues and you do not have to put skips and alike.